# How to find files which do not end with ".log" in bash/shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

I am new to bash/shell scripting. 
I want to find all the files in directory and subdirectories, which do not end with “.log”. 
I know I can use the below command to get the files which ends with “.log”, but I need the ones which do not end with this extension:

```
find /tmp/mallik5/ -iname "*.log"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `find` expression can make it:

```
find /tmp/mallik5/ ! -name "*.log"
```

If you just look for files, add `-type f`:

```
find /tmp/mallik5/ -type f ! -name "*.log"
```

Comment: Does not work with BSD based find tool, only GNU ones, limiting its portability.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /tmp/mallik5 -type f ! -name '*.log'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are half way through, by yourself in achieving the task by knowing GNU Find util is the apt tool.

**Couple of Quick Solutions will be** :

```
find /tmp/mallik5/ -not -name *.log
find /tmp/mallik5/ ! -name *.log
```

If you are trying to take action on the result of find, you can try:

```
find /tmp/mallik5/ -not -name *.log -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

The above line helps you to find and remove the files with names not ending with *.log

Knowledge on **Pattern Matching** is the key to solve the task, to learn more. [Click Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

To learn more on **GNU find** utility, [visit here](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Top)